# How to decrypt a string which hashed using Asp.Net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net Identity password hasher in my project. Now I need to get the real strings from the hashed string. What can I do to return the real string from the hashed string?

```
private Microsoft.AspNet.IdentityIPasswordHasher _passwordHasher;
string hashedString = _passwordHasher.HashPassword('realstring');
```

This is the code I used for hashing the string:

```
string realString = _passwordHasher.UnHashPassword('hashedstring');
```

Comment: ASP.Net Identity uses one way hashing algorithm. So, you cannot get the original password back.

Comment: @Corporalis I need the real password for logging in, but I know only the hashed password now.

Comment: @anverali What you need and what you can get are two different things, hashes are one-way, non-reversable.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is one way "scrambling" process. There is no (easy) way to get the password back - that is the purpose of hashing. If you need to compare password with the hash - has provided password and compare generated hash with the stored hash. But that should be handled for you by Identity framework.